# Delete .htaccess with Python ftplib

Tags: python, .htaccess, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to add FTP functionality into my Python 3 script using only ftplib or other libraries that are included with Python.  The script needs to delete a directory from an FTP server in order to remove an active web page from our website.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to delete the .htaccess file using ftplib and I can't delete the directory because it is not empty.

Some people have said that this is a hidden file, and have explained how to list hidden files, but I need to delete the file, not list it.    My .htaccess file also has full permissions and it can be successfully deleted using most other FTP clients.

Sample code:

```
files = list(ftp.nlst(myDirectory))     
for f in files:
    ftp.delete(f)

ftp.rmd(myDirectory)
```

**Update:** I was able to get everything working correctly, here is the complete code:

```
ftp.cwd(myDirectory)  # move to the dir to be deleted

    #upload placeholder .htaccess in case there is none in the dir and then delete it
    files01 = "c:\\files\\.htaccess"
    with open(files01, 'rb') as f:  
        ftp.storlines('STOR %s' % '.htaccess', f)

    ftp.delete(".htaccess")
    print("Successfully deleted .htaccess file in " + myDirectory)


    files = list(ftp.nlst(myDirectory))     # delete files in dir
    for f in files:
        ftp.delete(f)
    print("Successfully deleted visible files in " + myDirectory)

    ftp.rmd(myDirectory)  # remote directory deletion 
    print("Successfully deleted the following directory: " + myDirectory)
```

Comment: *"need to delete the file, not list it"* --- I do not think you are correct here. I assume that if you call `ftp.delete(".htaccess")`, the file would get **deleted**, right? Your problem is that `nlst` does not **list** the file.

Comment: It seems that you are correct!   I think the only reason why I couldn't delete the file was because I was trying to do something like this:  ftp.delete("/htdocs/test/somedir/.htaccess") rather than ftp.cwd(/htdocs/test/somedir/) followed by ftp.delete(".htaccess").